# How to display page excerpt in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new in using Wordpress, I created a page that contains a long list of items.

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
* Item 4 ... and so on
```

I am planning to embed this page with long list of items on a separate page. How am I going to do it?
I followed tutorials online and got the idea of putting this piece of code `add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );` on `functions.php`. After putting the code, an new option will be available when you create/edit pages. But after that, how can I display the my page excerpt?

Answer (score 17):

First to put this code on your theme function.php  file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

After that enable excerpt for page see below define image:

[image: Showing excerpt]

Using this code to get page excerpt:

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php 
    query_posts("page_id=36");
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()
?>
    <h1><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: I followed the same step as yours, but where will I use/place the code `echo get_the_excerpt();`? I think I read it somewhere that they use `the_excerpt()`.

Comment: you can use in your page while loop.
i have add one example which show page excerpt.

Comment: <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> and  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>  both working on same. but <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> in must be define "echo":